# extract data between tags <t> </t>

Tags: shell, unix

I have a data like below
How to print the data which is between two tags  
I want the data to be command-separated csv format

My approach was to convert data to horizontal format and then cut after every 4th column and convert to vertical

Data in xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
-
<sst uniqueCount="12" count="12"
    xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
-
    <si>
        <t>"NAME"</t>
    </si>
-
    <si>
        <t>"Vikas"</t>
    </si>
-
    <si>
        <t>"Vijay"</t>
    </si>
-
    <si>
        <t>"Vilas"</t>
    </si>
-
    <si>
        <t>"AGE"</t>
    </si>
-
    <si>
        <t>"24"</t>
    </si>
-
    <si>
        <t>"34"</t>
    </si>
-
    <si>
        <t>"35"</t>
    </si>
-
    <si>
        <t>"COURSE"</t>
    </si>
-
    <si>
        <t>"MCA"</t>
    </si>
-
    <si>
        <t>"MMS"</t>
    </si>
-
    <si>
        <t>"MBA"</t>
    </si>
</sst>
```

**I have tried this below command not working ..**

```
awk '/<t/{flag=1;next}/<t/{flag=0}flag' abc.xml
```

**Even tried this below command , it gives data but in single line**

```
awk -F'(</*t>|</*t>)' 'NF>1{for(i=2;i<NF; i=i+2) printf("%s%s", $i, (i+1==NF)?ORS:OFS)}' OFS=',' demo.xml
```

I want below data as output

```
NAME,AGE,Course
Vikas,"25",MCA
Prabhash,"34",MBA
Arjun,"21",MMS
```

Comment: Could you please do post your samples of data in your question in text form so that we could test our code before posting it, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Ok sure 2 minutes

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  Just try now i have paste the actual xml code

Comment: Thanks for editing it. Shouldn't your `<t>AGE</t>` should come before all your lines like `<t>"25"</t>`? Also do you have a tool like xmlstarlet installed in your system? Kindly do let me know on these 2 questions, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 checking 2 minutes

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Sorry my bad i by mistake added wrong xml data .. now i have updated just check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples only could you please try following.

```
awk -v OFS="," '
!NF || /^-$/{ next }
/<t>"COURSE"<\/t>/{
  foundAge=foundName=""
  foundCourse=1
  count=0
}
/<t>"AGE"<\/t>/{
  foundAge=1
  foundName=""
  count=0
}
/<t>"NAME"<\/t>/{
  foundName=1
  count=0
}
foundAge && match($0,/>[^<]*/){
  age[++count]=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
}
foundName && match($0,/>[^<]*/){
  name[++count]=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
}
foundCourse && match($0,/>[^<]*/){
  course[++count]=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
}
END{
  for(k=1;k<=count;k++){
    if(name[k]){
      print name[k],age[k],course[k]
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v OFS="," '                                 ##Starting awk program from here.
!NF || /^-$/{ next }                             ##if line is empty or starts with - then skip that line.
/<t>"COURSE"<\/t>/{                              ##Checking if line has <t>"COURSE"</t> then do following.
  foundAge=foundName=""                          ##Nullifying foundAge and foundName here.
  foundCourse=1                                  ##Setting foundCourse to 1 here.
  count=0                                        ##Setting count to 0 here.
}
/<t>"AGE"<\/t>/{                                 ##Checking if line has <t>"AGE"</t> then do following.
  foundAge=1                                     ##Setting foundAge to 1 here.
  foundName=foundCourse=""                       ##Nullifying foundName and foundCourse here.
  count=0                                        ##Setting count to 0 here.
}
/<t>"NAME"<\/t>/{                                ##Checking if line has <t>"NAME"</t> then do following.
  foundName=1                                    ##Setting foundName to 1 here.
  count=0                                        ##Setting count to 0 here.
}
foundAge && match($0,/>[^<]*/){                  ##Checking if foundAge is set and using match function to get values from > to till < here.
  age[++count]=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)     ##Creating age with index of count and having matched regex value here.
}
foundName && match($0,/>[^<]*/){                 ##Checking if foundName is set and using match function to get values from > to till < here.
  name[++count]=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)    ##Creating name with index of count and having matched regex value here.
}
foundCourse && match($0,/>[^<]*/){               ##Checking if foundCourse is set and using match function to get values from > to till < here.
  course[++count]=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)  ##Creating course with index of count and having matched regex value here.
}
END{                                             ##Starting END block of this awk program from here.
  for(k=1;k<=count;k++){                         ##Traversing through all elements of name here.
    if(name[k]){
      print name[k],age[k],course[k]             ##Printing respective array values here.
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file                                    ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** As per OP's comment, if all values needed in one line then try following:

```
awk -v OFS="," '
!NF || /^-$/{ next }
/<t>"COURSE"<\/t>/{
  foundAge=foundName=""
  foundCourse=1
  count=0
}
/<t>"AGE"<\/t>/{
  foundAge=1
  foundName=""
  count=0
}
/<t>"NAME"<\/t>/{
  foundName=1
  count=0
}
foundAge && match($0,/>[^<]*/){
  age[++count]=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
}
foundName && match($0,/>[^<]*/){
  name[++count]=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
}
foundCourse && match($0,/>[^<]*/){
  course[++count]=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
}
END{
  for(k=1;k<=count;k++){
     if(name[k]){
     nameVal=(nameVal?nameVal OFS:"")name[k]
     ageVal=(ageVal?ageVal OFS:"")age[k]
     courseVal=(courseVal?courseVal OFS:"")course[k]
     }
  }
  print nameVal,ageVal,courseVal
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Awsome bro can you add some descritpion what you code actually does at each line

Comment: @codeholic24, yeah that's in progress will do in a min or so.

Comment: @codeholic24, hey one more thing which I requested to check before too, you can't install any software like xmlstarlet etc in your box? Kindly confirm once(explanation is in porgress), cheers.

Comment: @ RavinderSingh13  are you able to convert data which is coming from this command to above output : `awk -F'(</*t>|</*t>)' 'NF>1{for(i=2;i<NF; i=i+2) printf("%s%s", $i, (i+1==NF)?ORS:OFS)}' OFS=',' demo.xml`

Comment: @codeholic24, ok, so you mean you are sending your awk command's output to my awk code? Please confirm once.

Comment: No i am just checking with second command how to get desired output which is in above question ...my approach was to cut after every 4th position and transpose

Comment: @ RavinderSingh13     : this output coming from second command mentioned in above question `"NAME","Vikas","Vijay","Vilas","AGE","24","34","35","COURSE","MCA","MMS","MBA"`   on this i am trying to transpose after 4th position

Comment: @codeholic24, I have added a very detailed level of explanation now, please do check it once.

Comment: One more help need is it possible for you to convert this text to above show output in question . The data will be in one line horizontal form `"NAME","Vikas","Vijay","Vilas","AGE","24","34","35","COURSE","MCA","MMS","MBA"`

Comment: @codeholic24, oh man, that will completely change the code, let me tweak it.

Comment: @codeholic24, I have tweaked the code now, please check my EDIT code, cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231566/discussion-between-codeholic24-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: I will join chat to discuss over it

Comment: @codeholic24, as I mentioned sorry I can' join it, please comment here.

Comment: What my approach was to get the details printed in one line horizontal line like this :  `"NAME","Vikas","Vijay","Vilas","AGE","24","34","35","COURSE","MCA","MMS","MBA"`  the giving user a input to enter at header names for suppose header i pass in array `{ NAME, AGE,COURSE}` when that match is found automatically it will make vertical that entire part

Comment: @codeholic24, I am sorry but this is totally different question from your original question, so please don't add more questions on your base question. You could open a new question with your efforts and we could discuss it there, else it may confuse future users who are referring this thread, cheers.

Comment: ya I am trying to add new question just check in few minutes

Comment: @codeholic24, sure opening a new question will be best thing as this question is already answered In my humble opinion, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: : Now check hope you will get what actually i trying to implement : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67251259/how-to-transpose-data-after-when-match-found-in-array