# How to transpose data after when match found in array

Tags: shell, unix

I want data to be in csv format from xml data

**xml data to test is available in this question**
[extract data between tags <t> </t>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67245123/extract-data-between-tags-t-t/67245640?noredirect=1#comment118870633_67245640)

**Note :** The data in xml file might differ and Headers will differ as well

In this xml their are 3 headers -> `NAME,AGE,COURSE`

**I have Used below command to get data in horizontal format ,all in one line :**

```
awk -F'(</*t>|</*t>)' 'NF>1{for(i=2;i<NF; i=i+2) printf("%s%s", $i, (i+1==NF)?ORS:OFS)}' OFS=',' demo.xml
```

**After running above command , below is the output**
"NAME","Vikas","Vijay","Vilas","AGE","24","34","35","COURSE","MCA","MMS","MBA"

**How i am trying to implement logic**

Take parameter from user , how many header values will be their

In above xml their are 3 headers -> `NAME,AGE,COURSE`

`header_count=3`

So 3 headers means will have 3 values like : `HEADER + 3` values
NAME,Vikas,Prabhas,Arjun -> this will be transpose to below

**Output :**

```
NAME,
Vikas,
Prabhas,
Arjun,
```

Same goes with header value **AGE** -> `AGE + 3` values

```
AGE,25,34,21  will be transpose to vertical 

AGE
25
34
21
```

Same goes with header value **COURSE** -> `COURSE + 3` values

```
COURSE,MCA,MBA,MMS  will be transpose to vertical 

COURSE
MCA
MBA
MMS
```

**Expected Output after combing all data for NAME,AGE,COURSE **

```
NAME,AGE,Course
Vikas,"25",MCA
Prabhash,"34",MBA
Arjun,"21",MMS
```

Comment: Please clarify the title of your question. You are talking about _arrays_, but there is no array in the code you posted, and indeed, POSIX shell does not have arrays anyway.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/^"NAME"/){
      found1=1
      found2=found3=""
    }
    if($i~/^"AGE"$/){
      found1=found2=""
      found2=1
    }
    if($i~/^"COURSE"$/){
      found1=found2=""
      found3=1
    }
    if(found1){
      name[++count1]=$i
    }
    if(found2){
      age[++count2]=$i
    }
    if(found3){
      course[++count3]=$i
    }
  }
}
END{
  if(count1>=count2 && count1>=count3){ max=count1 }
  if(count2>=count1 && count2>=count3){ max=count2 }
  if(count3>=count1 && count3>=count2){ max=count3 }
  for(i=1;i<=max;i++){
      print (name[i]?name[i]:"NA",age[i]?age[i]:"NA",course[i]?course[i]:"NA")
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Will write explanation after sometime.

Comment: Bro will you be able to use sequence : seq 4 | tr '\n' so that it will break after every 4th record and vertical record and append the next 4

Comment: : I have tried this command but giving -> first column data how to get next record data and append it to above data

Comment: @codeholic24, it worked perfectly fine for me when I tested it. You have only single line in your file right?

Comment: ya for me too worked .. but what i am saying is their any other method to do it instead of taking headers implicitly in code it self  that's why i said my data appears in one single line horizontal : `"NAME","Vikas","Vijay","Vilas","AGE","24","34","35","COURSE","MCA","MMS","MBA"`  and this need to split after 4th value to vertical and same with next and append

Comment: this command does it : `echo $str | cut -d',' -f1-4 | tr ',' '\n' | awk '{print $0, ","}'`  but prints only first column and how to achieve the other values and append it                         str=`"NAME","Vikas","Vijay","Vilas","AGE","24","34","35","COURSE","MCA","MMS","MBA"`

Comment: @codeholic24, trust me this is one of the GENERIC code I had written here. Could you please explain more what improvement you looking here?

Comment: is their any other way to get connected to you through call  will discuss in detail

Comment: @codeholic24, we could chat here :) let me know what exactly you are looking, code I given is generic in a way means in case there are n number of values of name, age, courses it will work.

Comment: the headers are going to differ now in this case 3 headers are their NAME , AGE , COURSE ..... where in future their might me few more headers

Comment: @codeholic24, ok then do you want them to get identify automatically? If yes then please do let me know what is the logic of it. I will edit the code as per that then.

Comment: @ RavinderSingh13  ok i will add the image and logic to above question

Comment: @codeholic24, please do it text form not in image else I will not able to test it

Comment: Now check the question  i have added logic how i am doing ... is their any other approach kindly share .. note the headers will differ .. it should be dynamic

Comment: @codeholic24, but my question is how I will know which value is heading? please do let me know on same.

Comment: @ RavinderSingh13   If that's the issue then ... i will be getting those headers names in a separate file , that file will have only headers names... will store it into array as a value ... as headers will be comma separated NAME,AGE,COURSE  -> array={ NAME,AGE,COURSE }  -> dynamically getting that values to array from file

Comment: I have one file called headers.txt => NAME,AGE,COURSE and the xml file you already have demo.xml  => how to dynamically create csv file using this both files is that the issue for me

Comment: @codeholic24, so you mean you need to read another file to see headers in main file? Please confirm once.

Comment: Yes that is what i am actually trying to tell you … i am trying to break down each thing into levels so that i will get how to process step by step that to dynamically create csv from headers and xml file

Comment: @codeholic24, does your other file have values like: `NAMES,COURSE,AGE` etc? Please confirm once.

Comment: Yes the other file called : headers.txt  will contain only headers values => `NAME , AGE ,COURSE`